# what is eating my memory? Windows 7 in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, memory

this is rather weird. I have a work laptop with Ubuntu and Windows 7 virtual machine in VirtualBox in it. In that VM I usually run just 2 RDP sessions, SciTE editor, Evernote, Total Commander, but once I start Excel or FireFox it starts to complain that the computer is low on memory and I should close somem programs! It has 2.3GB of RAM assigned, so how can this amount of memory not be enough for these apps? I remember using a Windows 7 machine with 512MB RAM just fine back in the old days. Task manager does not really help me with that. Any idea what could be holding all this?

Paging file is set to system managed for C drive and there is 10GB free out of 40GB total on C:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

c:\pagefile.sys file was 960MB, but when I got into settings I get this error. Then I saw it was "no pagefile", so I set it again to system managed. But anyway, shouldn't it work without pagefile also? What is using 2GB of RAM? I can't see it in Process Explorer either.

EDIT2:
so pagefile seems to be working now, but I am still curious why is commit so high and what does this number actually consist of...
[image]

Comment: You can see that the commit size is close to the commit limit, 2123/2333. Yet the task manager table doesn't show any processes accounting for that much commit usage. Is it showing processes from all users? Are you 100% sure the pagefile is set to system managed?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz He might not be running Task Manager as an admin.

Comment: Try running [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) as an admin. Sort by working set (highest to lowest) and give us a screenshot of the top results.

Comment: Commit size is more useful than working set. It's commit that he's running out of, not RAM. (He has about 1400MB of RAM available but only about 200MB of commit. Something is reserving memory it's not using.)

Comment: question edited with pics and comment at the end added

Comment: Could you sort by Private Bytes instead of Working Set?

Comment: It will not work correctly unless the paging file is working. An improperly set paging file will make it impossible to use RAM effectively, resulting in what you're seeing. (Note that the page file does not have to actually be used, it just has to exist and be working.)

Comment: So maybe I fixed that by setting pagefile again. But I am still interested in that commit size. See new pic

Comment: That looks better. I think you fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official minimum memory requirement for Windows 7, 64-bit is 2GB. You have that. So you should be okay. But it's a bit tight. That means you need to be able to make use of RAM effectively. Without a working page file, you can't do that. Fix the page file and the problem will go away. The page file will likely not be used, it just needs to be available.

It's a bit complicated to explain accurately, so permit me a grossly oversimplified explanation. Imagine if a process asks Windows to reserve 1GB for it. You'd be pretty annoyed if it said no. You have lots of RAM free, more than 1GB, and the program only wants 1GB. So Windows says yes. But say that process doesn't use any of that memory. Still, Windows can't assume it won't, so it has 1GB of RAM that it can't let any other process reserve. Ouch.

With a working pagefile, Windows knows that it can make free RAM whenever it needs it by writing to the page file. So it can let other processes use and reserve memory without having to fear that it will promise more than it can deliver.

With no page file available, Windows can't commit more memory than it has RAM, and that makes for horrifically inefficient use of RAM.

Comment: To answer OP's other question, the commit size is the amount of memory used by a process across both RAM and the page file. Since the size of your page file defaults to twice the amount of RAM you have, it's not uncommon to have the commit size of resource-intensive programs exceed the amount of RAM you have installed.

Comment: And the commit limit is the maximum amount of memory the process can use without having to ask the OS for more memory than it has already asked for. This can need to be much greater than the amount of RAM even with no pagefile in use. With no page file, the commit limit cannot exceed the size of RAM, and that's awful for a machine that doesn't have much more RAM than it needs.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Excellent answer.  I was just going to point out the error, the author was getting, was indicating the system was running out of virtual memory not physical memory.